# onmouseover() to invoke onclick after 1 second?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an element:

```
<b onclick="alert('');" onmouseover="this.style.color='red'; setTimeout('........', 1000);" onmouseout="this.style.color='';">123</b>
```

I need that when element is mouseovered and after 1 second the mouse cursor continue staying above this element, then onclick() event of this element should start.

In other words, what should be instead of '..............' in onmouseover() event?

Comment: So if the user hovers over the element for a full second, invoke the event, as opposed to invoking it immediately?

Comment: Why not set a timer in on onmouseover and remove the timer onmouseout?  The event the timer would trigger would be whatever you want to happen after 1 second.

Comment: @user1161318 seems like good solution, but how to remove the timeout event? I mean, crossbrowser removing of event.

Comment: You should be able to store the timer in an id and use that to clear it out.  Here's a page with details: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.countdown = setTimeout(function(){this.click();}, 1000);
```

Additionally, you need to clear the interval in the mouseout handler:

```
clearTimeout(countdown);
```

Ideally you would give your element an ID and use the new event registration model:

```
var e = document.getElementById('myelement');
e.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert('');
});
e.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
    var self = this;
    this.style.color='red';
    window.countdown = setTimeout(function(){self.click();}, 1000);
});
e.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
    this.style.color='';
    clearTimeout(countdown);
});
```

Comment: But if there are more then 1 element and they are nested, so countdown may be overlapped by several onmouseover events?

Comment: @EL Then you should be using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, not `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: no problem with mouseenter/mouseleave P.S. Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'this.click' is not a function

Comment: Ok, it work with "setTimeout(this.onclick,1000);" but it throws another error about "onclick" event: Cannot convert 'this.parentNode' to object" (onclick="this.parentNode.title='123';)

Comment: Yeah you're right. It seems that without id it couldn't be done. =(

Comment: @EL It can be done. You could use the exact same code I've posted in inline event handlers. It just isn't recommended.

Comment: doesn't work. onclick="this.parentNode.title='123'; ->> Cannot convert 'this.parentNode' to object

Comment: @EL Where did `parentNode` come from? It isn't in your question, and it isn't in my answer.

Comment: you're right, but if onclick="alert(this);" then it will return not HTMLelement, but "Object window". I mean 'this' in setTimeot() becomes different then 'this' in onclick, onmouseover and other events.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20705/discussion-between-e-l-and-asad)

Comment: @EL No, I prefer not to. What is wrong with using event registration?

Answer (score 1):

You should start the interval on mouse over event as a global variable to refer on mouse out event to clear it like @Asad said.

```
<b onclick = "alert()"
 onmouseover = "window.countdown = setTimeout(function(){this.click();}, 1000);"
 onmouseout = "clearTimeout(countdown)">
 123
</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do some extra work, and this won't work out very well for you inside of inline Javascript. This is all pseudocode so I don't recommend copy/pasting!

```
// We'll need to create an interval and store it
var timerInterval = {}
// And keep track of how many seconds have elapsed   
var timeElapsedInSeconds = 0;

function tick (){
   timeElapsedInSeconds++;
   if (timeElapsedInSeconds > 0){
       // YOUR GREAT CODE HERE
   }
   // Either way, let's be sure to reset everything.
   resetTimer();
}

function hoverOverHandler (){
   // Start our timer on hover 
   timerInterval = window.setInterval(tick, 1000);    
}

function resetTimer () {
   timeElapsedInSeconds = 0;
   window.clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function hoverOutHandler () {
   // Kill timer on hoverout
   resetTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some trick with dynamic id and this is what came out:

```
<b style="color:red;" onclick="if(this.style.color!='green'){return false;}else{this.style.color='red';} alert(this.parentNode);" onmouseover="if(this.style.color!='green'){var newID='tmpID_'+Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000)); if(this.id==''){this.id=newID;} setTimeout('top.document.getElementById(\''+this.id+'\').onclick();',1000); this.style.color='green';}" onmouseout="this.style.color='red';">click</b>
```

crossbrowsered =)